# Get and decode json with php

Tags: php, json

I'm sure this is similar to other questions, but I have tried the solutions, and couldn't get it to work.

I'm trying to get the location of an IP address, decode the json, and print it. I actually plan to put it into a database, but Im not even sure why I cant get anything to print to the screen.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=".$ip);
$local = json_decode($json,true);
```

thanks.

Comment: can you ensure your error reporting is on and include what is echoed on var_dump($local)

Comment: What version of php you are using? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php -> available for PHP >= 5.2

Comment: What does `var_dump($json); var_dump($local)` return? Is `file_get_contents` allowed to use remote URLs in your server settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the code you've provided does not actually print anything, which would explain why you're getting a blank screen. I assume you're doing something like `echo $local;` later in the program, but if not, that'll be the problem.

Assuming that isn't the issue....

Two possibilities:

1. `file_get_contents()` is returning an error.
2. `json_decode()` is returning an error.

Firstly, you should add some additional error trapping in your code to determine which one is the problem.

If you have PHP set to not display errors, consider switching them on so you can see any errors that are generated. Or else look at your server log to see the errors.

`file_get_contents()` may fail if the URL is invalid. It may also fail if your PHP installation is set to not allow URLs via the file handling functions. If this is the case you'll need to change your php.ini settings. If you can't do that, you'll have to load the file via a different method (eg Curl).

`json_decode()` is only likely to fail if the string it gets is invalid JSON. You should check the output of the URL to confirm that it looks right, and check it something like firebug to ensure it is valid.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ...load the file via a different method (eg Curl).

Answer (score 1):

A. When you mean `I cant get anything to print to the screen.` definitely you can get anything because you did not output anything to screen.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=".$ip);
$local = json_decode($json,true);

echo $local['city'] ;
print  $local['country_name'] ;

var_dump($local);
```

B. It would also mean that `allow_url_include set to Off` which would not allow `file_get_contents` load a information from another domain